# Check entire .net solution to verify code is not only used for test

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, architecture

I'm trying to find code that is only being used for unit tests.

I've experimented with ArchUnitNET and NetArchTest, but the documentation is rather limited, and a can't for the love of all that holy figure out how to test it.
It seems rather straight forward, though

Types that are in namespaces I want to verify,
should have methods called from
namespaces other than those named with 'test'

Maybe I'm looking at it all wrong.
For ArchUnitNet I'm trying something along the line of:

```
var myTypes = Types().That()
              .ResideInNamespace("^MyTypes.*", true)
              .And().DoNotResideInNamespace(".*(?i)Test.*", true) // because *Test* are the ones we try to avoid
              .As("Types that are not in 'Test' ");
      
       //OR:
       MethodMembers()
           .That().AreDeclaredIn(myTypes)
           .And().AreNoConstructors()
           .And().AreNotPrivate()
           .Should().BeCalledBy(myTypes)
        .Check(architecture);
       
       
       MethodMembers()
           .That().AreCalledBy( Types().That().ResideInNamespace(".*(?i)Test.*", true) )
           .Should().CallAny(
                  MethodMembers().That()
                            .AreDeclaredIn(myTypes)
        )
       .Check(architecture);
```

In NetArchTest it seems i need to make my own custom rule along the lines of:

```
[Test]
public void Types_Hopefully_Not_Only_Called_From_Test()
{
       var types = Types.InCurrentDomain();

       var typesNotInTest = types.That()
                            .ResideInNamespaceMatching("^MyTypes.*")
                            .And().DoNotResideInNamespaceMatching(".*(?i)Test.*"); // because Test are the ones we try to avoid
      
       var anotherResult = typesNotInTest.Should().MeetCustomRule(new IsCalledFromAjourNameSpace() ).GetResult();

       Assert.IsTrue(anotherResult.IsSuccessful, "Some Types are only used for Tests");
}
private class IsCalledFromAjourNameSpace : ICustomRule
{
  //private Regex _testRegex = new Regex(".*(?i)Test.*");
    private Regex _myTypesRegex = new Regex("^MyTypes.*");
    public bool MeetsRule(TypeDefinition type)
    {
      return type.Methods
               .Where(method => method.IsPublic && method.IsConstructor == false)
               .Any(m=> _myTypesRegex.IsMatch(m.DeclaringType.Namespace)
      );
     }
}
```

Hopefully someone is more architechtual than me.. 'cause I'm obviously missing something :-)

Comment: What exactly is it that isn't working? What results are you getting, what did you expect?

Comment: I'm getting a lot of 'noise', where eg. methods that are compiled from setters and getters, or methods from classes, that are not actually called on their own, but through the interface they implement..
I was hoping for fairly simple test, that would show me which classes that was ONLY called from a '*test*' namespace.. Or maybe hear from someone who knows a bit about it, and could guide me in another direction, if this approach is just silly

Comment: @Newnamtab Did you find a solution?

Comment: KristofferJälén Nope! Ended up manually going through projects, using code inspection to look for references to 'test' projects.